# How to make a system-wise command alias on macOS

Tags: java, macos, terminal, macos-big-sur

I want to execute some old code in java, but it's becoming complicated with old versions of it. Therefore, I wanted to create my "Java aliases" so the command "java11" would execute the java 11 binary command. Unfortunately, on mac, I was not successful.

I tried to follow tutorials wanting to add an alias part in your ~/.zshrc. I did that, and it works perfectly, but it doesn't work for bash scripts, which is really annoying.

Here is the line for my java11 alias in the .zshrc:

```
alias java11="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java $@"
```

(I don't know if it would do anything, but I also added the alias lines in my .bashrc)

Comment: Don't use `$@` in aliases, they don't take arguments. Also, since it's in double-quotes, it'll expand to the aliases that exist *when the alias is defined*, not when it's used. Also, aliases are disabled by default in scripts. What about just defining a symlink from /usr/local/bin/java11 to the "correct" java executable?

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for the advice ! I didn't know that "$@" was useless in aliases, neither did I know about /usr/local/bin. This is very useful. You should probably post the last part of your comment as an answer, because that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases have limited usefulness for things like this. They need to be configured in a shell initialization file (and *which* file is used depends on the shell, what mode it's started in, etc), they're disabled by default in scripts, and they aren't available at all when the command is executed by something other than a shell (e.g. in `sudo java11 ...`, it's `sudo` that does the execution, and it doesn't know anything about aliases).

I'd recommend creating an actual command instead. Since this is just another name for an existing binary (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java), you can just use a symbolic link to the original binary (for something more complex, it might make sense to create a wrapper script instead). /usr/local/bin doesn't exist by default in macOS, but it is in the default `PATH` (in most contexts except `cron` jobs, grrr), so if you create it, it'll be searched automatically. So something like this should work:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java /usr/local/bin/java11
```

In your running zsh sessions, you'll probably have to run `rehash` to get them to notice the new binary. And remove the alias, to keep it from overriding the new command.